# tomcat constant pool size

Tags: tomcat, pool

I have this configuration for connection pool the connections are always replaced  ,  i need a configuration for 200 connections that won't be replaced.

hope someone can help?
thanks

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"          
          initialSize="150"
          minidle="150"
          maxWait="5000"          
          maxActive="150"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"
          username="user"
          password="password"
          driverClassName="com.jcc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:db2://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:50000/mydb"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the connections are always replaced"?